# How to estimate the upper bound of Cramer's bounded logit model?

Tags: r, logistic, likelihood

I've recently came accross the paper *[Scoring bank loans that may go wrong: a case study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9574.2004.00127.x)* by J.S Cramer in which he describes a simple modification of the logit model but i can't find a way to reproduce his work.

Cramer proposes that in Low Default Portfolios, the addition of an upper-bound() to the probability of default is capable of improving the model perfomance.

[image]

I'm fairly acquainted with R but i couldn't find a function that reproduces the bounded logit or an article that could help me write an equivalent function. How can i estimate a bounded logit?

Comment: You could program the loglikelihood function yourself, and then use some generic optimizer.  See last chapter (16) in Venables & Ripley's MASS (fourth edition) which has examples.